# Recyclerview inside another recyclerview changes item height after scrolling up or down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working with a recyclerView which contains another recyclerview.
My issue is that the height of the containing recyclerview changes after scrolling down or up the main recyclerview. Each item reduces its height after scrolling down or up the main recyclerview.

This is the containing recyclerview layout:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/exo_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"


        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:autoPlay="false"
        app:showFullScreenButton="false" />


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This the adapter for the containing recyclerview:

```
public class PostMediaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostMediaAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    public static String MISDATOS= "MisDatos";
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<MediaPost> mediaList;

    private final static String expression = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";

    SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView;
    SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    LinearLayout linear;

    public FragmentManager f_manager;

    public PostMediaAdapter(Context mCtx, List<MediaPost> mediaList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.mediaList = mediaList;

    }






    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {



        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts_media_list, null);


        Log.d(("crear spot"),"ich bin in" +"PostMediaAdapter");

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowmanager = (WindowManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowmanager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "deviceWidth " +deviceWidth);
        view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);





    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {


        MediaPost media = mediaList.get(position);


        String tipo = media.getUsers1();
        String archivo = media.getUsers2();
        Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "deviceWidth tipo media " +tipo);
        Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "deviceWidth tipo archivo " +archivo);

        if (tipo.equals("video")){
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //    holder.youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.exoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "tipo video  " +media.getUsers2());
            try {


                BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
                TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
                exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mCtx, trackSelector);

                Uri video=Uri.parse(media.getUsers2());
                Uri videoURI = video;

                DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
                ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
                MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

                holder.exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
                exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
                exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                holder.exoPlayerView.setBackgroundResource(grey_900);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("MainAcvtivity"," exoplayer error "+ e.toString());
            }
        }
        if (tipo.equals("imagen")){

            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "tipo imagen  " +media.getUsers2());
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.exoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          holder.youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Glide.with(mCtx)
                    .load(media.getUsers2())
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }
        if (tipo.equals("vacio")){


            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.exoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          holder.youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
        if (tipo.equals("youtube")){
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.exoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.youTubePlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "tipo youtube  " +media.getUsers2());




            String videoyoutube = media.getUsers2();

            String videoId =  getVideoId(videoyoutube);


            ((HomeActivity) (mCtx)).getLifecycle().addObserver(holder.youTubePlayerView);
            holder.youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {

                    String videoyoutube = media.getUsers2();

                    String videoId =  getVideoId(videoyoutube);

                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
                    youTubePlayer.pause();

                }
            });




        }
```

If you need the code or layout for the main recyclerview, I can include them without problems.

EDIT

Screenshot from main recyclerview first item.
The containing recyclerview is where you can find the bike picture.

[image]

Second screenshot after a complete down and up scroll from the main recyclerview.

[image]

You may see that after every scroll down or up, the item is smaller in height.

Main RecyclerView Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:padding="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="16dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            card_view:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            card_view:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
            android:text="Sample"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_700"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/layout_deporte2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_deportes1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tres"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp1"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp2"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp3"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp4"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_deporte2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_deportes1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tres"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp5"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp6"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp7"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp8"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:visibility="visible"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />


        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:text="Vivimos rodeados de objetos cotidianos que, a pesar de verlos cada día, todavía no tenemos muy claro para qué sirven. Es el caso del cuadrado con dos ranuras que tienen algunas mochilas, el bolsillo pequeño de los vaqueros, sus remaches de cobre e incluso las siglas 'YKK' que aparecen en tu cremallera. ¿Alguna vez te habías preguntado para qué sirven los agujeros laterales de algunas zapatillas?    "
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tres"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_submenu" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tresnocreador"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_submenu" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAmbassador"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spot_sport"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/skate" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tipo_spot"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/spot_sport"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/negocio" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/spot_map"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tipo_spot"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tipo_spot"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_pin_mapa" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/verified"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spot_map"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:text="Skatepark Macba, Barcelona, Spain"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/verified"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/spot_map"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtVerified"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVerified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/verified"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:text="Verified"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/spot_sport"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >

        </com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/spot_sport"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fire"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:src="@drawable/home_fire_desactivado"


             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFireOnOff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtFire"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comments"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtFire"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:src="@drawable/home_comentarios"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fixpin"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtComments"
            android:background="@drawable/circle"
            android:src="@drawable/checknegrosincirculo"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEstadoAqui"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fixpin"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fixpin"

            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:lines="3"
            android:text="@string/have_you_been_here"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFire"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fixpin"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fire"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:lines="2"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/recyclerMarcas"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fixpin"

            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/comments"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="10 comments"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtComentarios"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/fire"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="@string/insert_comments"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_below="@id/edtComentarios"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorMovMap"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/linearGente"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnEnviar"

            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView26"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/have_been_here"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvGente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todosComentarios"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearGente"
            android:duplicateParentState="false"

            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Main RV Adapter:

```
PostMediaAdapter adapter = new PostMediaAdapter(context, mediaList);
holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(holder.recyclerView);



holder.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new CirclePagerIndicatorDecoration());
```

Comment: Why do you change your items height from wrap_content to match_parent in your both adapters programmatically?=) It is the problem, which you try yo find.

Comment: @OlegSkidan, what do  you mean?

Comment: You use `view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));` but your layout has correct height `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. You force each your item to change its height. Every scrolling call recycling for some items and reuse old height. It will bigger and bigger every time. Just try to hide this lines and check again. If it works, I will create an answer with explanations.

Comment: @OlegSkidan, then I only need to remove this line at the adapter?

Comment: @OlegSkidan, let me try it out

Comment: could you try remove all lines from `Log.d(("crear spot")` to your return statement?

Comment: @OlegSkidan, if I remove those lines then the items are not shown.

Comment: Try to write this line `view.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(deviceWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` instead of yours

Comment: @OlegSkidan, I have already tried it now, no changes after that, the issue is there, everytime that I make a complete scroll down and scroll up the containing recyclerview height is about 5 to 10 dp smaller

Comment: @OlegSkidan i can put some screenshots to show you the issue, if you want.

Comment: What is the main purpose for using display metrics in your adapter? Why you can not to make your cardview with match_parent width and wrap_content/match_parent height proper in your item layout file?

Comment: @OlegSkidan, I am simulating a slideshow that can contain picture, videos and youtube videos. It is used to show the small dots above.

Comment: please post some screenshots or gif

Comment: @OlegSkidan, done

Comment: It seems, like only one view change it size - it is image view. Can you try never hide it? An example: Use 20 dummy items with `imagen`. Does it ever change it size? Some times ago i have the same problems. My cardView had an image, and sometimes i hid it. But in my cas some of items became bigger.

Comment: @OlegSkidan, It changes only the containing recyclerview height , all other views from the main recyclerview are not changing. You can see in the containing adapter code that the view can hold an image, a video or a youtube video. I guess the problem lies in the layout from the adapter.

Comment: paste your main RV item layout and code

Comment: @OlegSkidan, done

Comment: Can you try to fix height of cardview1?

Comment: @OlegSkidan, yes, I have put its height at 250dp, the same than image, video and youtube, but same result

Comment: Your RV has fixed match parent... maybe it's better to add fixed size there? or set background of your RV (black) for make sure, that RV change it size, not items.

Comment: @OlegSkidan, done,I have changed the background color of rv and it is changing its size, not the items

Comment: Could you try to use constraint layout for the main adapter item? Also you can try to remove your snap helper

Comment: @OlegSkidan, solved. I have put as background from the cardview a transparent image.